# How to follow redirects with cURL, but ignore 302 (Moved Temporarily)

Tags: shell, curl, redirect, sh

I'm writing a script that will be used to download various files using cURL. Currently, I'm using `curl -L` to follow redirects, but I have noticed that some URLs redirect to search engines using a 302 (Moved Temporarily) response. Is there a way to follow redirects, but specifically ignore the 302 response code?

Example #1: Valid URL

`curl -LOJ "https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?linkid=2009112"` downloads the correct file to the current working directory.

Example #2: Invalid URL

`curl -LOJ "https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?linkid=2"` creates the filename "?linkid=2" in the current working directory after following a 302 response that forwards the request to Bing.

Comment: I don't see how this is a question about the POSIX standard (which doesn't specify curl at all), unless you mean the answer needs to work with POSIX sh? Probably better to just add a `sh` tag in that case.

Comment: Unfortunately, I _suspect_ that to get this behavior you'll need to drop `-L` and implement the redirection behavior yourself.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy updated to reflect that. Ty for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I found no problem I used only the  -L option.

That link returns over a over 2 GB response.  My PHP ran out of memory.

wget worked fine.

curl on the Windows command line worked fine:

```
curl -L https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?linkid=2 --output Microsoft_Office_16.66.22101101_BusinessPro_Installer.pkg
```

I do not understand your Example #2 url to `?linkid=2"`
I am assuming a typo.
Although it did download the 2784k Bing page.
It was an invalid linkid.  
Invalid linkid's will take you to Bing.

Comment: That is where the problem lies. The hope is by ignoring a 302 (Moved Temporarily) I can avoid getting redirected to Bing or another search engine, and instead fail. The first example shows a valid redirect while the second example shows a redirect that I want to avoid.